# Statistical significance with Newey–West standard errors with a one-lag correction used

Tags: statistical-significance, python, least-squares, neweywest

I am trying to do statistical test to prove that the returns of a certain equity are statistically significant so that I can reject the null hypothesis that the mean (of returns) is equal to 0.
I have done the following:

```
t, p = sc.stats.ttest_1samp(returns.values, 0)
```

Obtained t-statistic 2.7402

Now, going one step further I have tried to do a NeweyWest t-statistic with one-lag correction.
The approach I took is modelling a intercept only OLS as follows:

```
model = sm.ols( formula = 'MKT ~ 1',data = mkt_data).fit()
new = model.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HAC',maxlags=1)
T_test = results.t_test(new.params) 
print(T_test)
```

```
                             Test for Constraints                             
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 c0           1.66e-07   6.06e-08      2.740      0.006    4.73e-08   2.85e-07
==============================================================================
```

where MKT is the market data that can be obtained from the Kenneth R. French’s data library for a period from December 1992 to October 2015.
Which would be nice and dandy, but I am comparing these results with a paper which for the same data obtains a t-statistic of **2.8305** and a standard error of **0.0001**.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more information to be able to answer this. In any case, since your t-statistics is not too far from the one in the paper, could it be that the paper uses a different number of lags? In financial applications it is not uncommon to use as many as 5 lags.